# Create a two tableview list using one TableViewController class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to do an sample application where in a view i have two buttons one is COUNTRY and another is STATE. 
when i click on a country button the country list should appear in a tableview class like a popup and when i click on state button state list should appear in a tableview like popup,So how can i do this please suggest with sample code.

NOTE:I should use only one TableViewcontroller class for both country and state Data list.

Comment: Pop-ups are not encouraged. The best way is to use a pickerview with two sections, one having all the countries, another with states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Code:

RootViewController.h

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {

UIButton *btnCountry;
UIButton *btnState;

NSMutableArray *tempArray;
NSMutableArray *countryArray;
NSMutableArray *stateArray;

IBOutlet UITableView *tempTable;
}

 @property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btnCountry;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *btnState;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *countryArray;
 @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *stateArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *tempArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tempTable;


- (IBAction) showState:(id)sender;
- (IBAction) showCountry:(id)sender;
```

@end

RootViewController.m

```
@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize btnState,btnCountry, stateArray,countryArray,tempArray;
@synthesize tempTable;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

tempTable.hidden = YES;

countryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",@"Pakistan",@"USA",nil];
stateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Gujarat",@"Maharashtra", @"Karnataka",nil];
tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}



- (IBAction) showCountry:(id)sender
{
btnCountry = (UIButton *)sender;
tempArray = countryArray;
[tempTable reloadData];
if([btnCountry isSelected])
{
    tempTable.hidden = YES;
    btnCountry.selected = NO;
}
else
{
    tempTable.hidden = NO;
    btnCountry.selected = YES;
}
}


- (IBAction) showState:(id)sender
{
btnState = (UIButton *)sender;
tempArray = stateArray;
[tempTable reloadData];

if([btnState isSelected])
{
    tempTable.hidden = YES;
    btnState.selected = NO;
}
else
{
    tempTable.hidden = NO;
    btnState.selected = YES;
}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section      {

return [tempArray count];
 }


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}


@end
```

Comment: ok. place the TableView on your nib of RootViewController and connect it to file's owner.    This code works nicely...

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear enough ,, what did you try? ..
But, You can use UIPopOverController for that 
see 
[THIS LINK](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development)

Or Just a Static UiTableView in the same Nib file ,, make it hidden when you don't need it .

Comment: ya i am  following the same link.In the above link when we click the button list appears.Same way i want to have one more button next to that, for example "countries"when i click countries list should appear using same tableViewController class.how do we do that?The data in the list should be different.

Comment: Lsn, make a nother class that has two methods one for the country and one for the state or anything else each function return an NSMutableArray ,, so you can call them in the Uitableviewcontroller class ,,
in the main nib file and when u call the uitableview class make sure to pass an argument that till the uitablview call which function to load into the table ,, this will take long time to accomplish but will save u some time when u add more tables !!
I hope you got it!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use One Tableview for this: Here i am attaching only the logic.

In viewdidload,

There will be two arrays countryArray and stateArray.

There will be a third array : tempArray

there are two  buttons: button1 and button2
tableview.hidden=YES;

in button1Action assign the countryArray to tempArray and also [tableview reload]

in button2Action assign the stateArray to tempArray and also [tableview reload]

then in tableview delegates,

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {

  return [tempArray count];

}

and then in

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

use tempArray.......

}

try this...and if you want more detailed  pls inform....

Answer (score 0):

Take Two tableViews and two Buttons.

Place each tableview below each of the button.

Initially both the TableViews are hidden. When the Button is clicked show the TableView with Animation.

Comment: No actually i need to use only one tableView because if need to hv more button list i cant keep adding more and more tableViews thats the reason.

Comment: Then take Two Temporary array(Country and State) and save data whatever you want to display in this array. Now when Country Button is selected assign value of Temporary array(Country) to TableView.ViceVersa

Comment: how can i do that as i am new to ios can i hv some sample code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only use one TableViewController but with different data sources.

Comment: how can i do that can i have some sample code??for one button i am using below linkhttp://mobiforge.com/designing/story/using-popoverview-ipad-app-development if i need to add one more button and differnt data list how can i do?